# How to fix the error [Failed to launch the site preview in 30 seconds] in Blogdown?

Tags: windows, rstudio, blogdown

I'm trying to build a website using blogdown on my windows 10 laptop and when I run `blogdown::serve_site()`, Rstudio tells me:

`Launching the server via the command: C:/Users/Tuan/AppData/Roaming/Hugo/0.109.0/hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -D -F --navigateToChanged SUCCESS: The process with PID 808 (child process of PID 7592) has been terminated. SUCCESS: The process with PID 7592 (child process of PID 9480) has been terminated.`

And also this error:

`Error: Failed to launch the site preview in 30 seconds. Try to give it more time via the global option "blogdown.server.timeout", e.g., options(blogdown.server.timeout = 600).`

I've tried restart R, reinstalling blogdown and updating packages but it's still the same.

How can I get rid of this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the error message and follow its suggestion?

Comment: @YihuiXie Yeah, I also tried typing "blogdown.server.timeout = 600" but I got the same error message again. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The error message suggests you use `options(blogdown.server.timeout = 600)` instead of typing `blogdown.server.timeout = 600`.

Comment: @YihuiXie I set that option and now it says `Error: Failed to launch the site preview in 600 seconds.` and still gives me the old suggestion `Try to give it more time via the global option "blogdown.server.timeout", e.g., options(blogdown.server.timeout = 600).`  What could be wrong in your opinion?

Comment: It's hard to tell. You may try `blogdown::build_site()` and see how long it takes.

Comment: It only takes a few seconds. `blogdown::build_site()` works fine but `blogdown::serve_site()`. I tried reinstalling Rstudio also. This is weird -_-

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? e.g. a Github repo. Also try `install.packages('processx')` and see if it works.